# How to block "Select *" but at the same time SELECT/READ permissions should be granted though in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant

I am not a database expert nor a fullstack developer.
I Have a database in PostgreSQL, where I need to give the database access towards the developers in read only mode, but still if I grant them the SELECT/READ Only permissions, talking in a programming perspective they would be able to run the query `SELECT * from table-name` and they would also get the whole data in JSON format as they are also dealing with API's.

So I need to give them the READ/SELECT only permissions and at the same time I need to block the `SELECT * from Tablename`.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. What is the difference between giving privileges for `select *` and "read/select" privilege? Do you want to grant select privilege to only certain columns?

Comment: So its ok if they `SELECT column1, column2.. FROM tablename` just not `SELECT * FROM tablename`?

Comment: Hello a_horse_with_no_name, i would like to grant select privilege in all columns but the developers should not be able to query the whole data from the nodejs scripts, and if they are able to use the SELECT *, then they can get the whole data in JSON format. The goal of these question is that the dev team should not be able to use SELECT * and at the same time he should not be able to perform CRUD operations in the table, so thats why READ/SELECT only privileges is being used.

Comment: Hello Martin Navarro, exactly its OK if they use SELECT column1,column2 but not just SELECT * from tablename.

Comment: "I would like grant select privileges to **all** columns" contradicts the statement "they should not be able to use `select *`". If you grant them access to all columns they there is no way to prevent `select *` because that means "all columns"

Comment: is there any otherway to prevent the "SELECT *" for example say that i add an additional dummy/test column and then i only provide SELECT privilege to all columns excluding the dummy/test column, then in this case, would the developer be able to access all the data using "SELECT *".

Comment: yes, that works. I just completed my answer, to see you proposing the same thing in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think this was possible, and it's probably not, but you can get very close.

If you grant select not on the table itself but on a proper subset of the columns that table has to the developers. they will not be able to issue `select *` queries.

So you need to add an extra column that is not used for data, but which you can deny access for from the devs. Optionally can add a check constraint to ensure that the unused column is always null.

The grant command goes like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ( list,of,"column",names) ON "table name" TO developers;
```

It must be a subset, if you grant all columns they will be allowed `select *`.

Comment: Hi Jasen, the solution that you provided just works fine when i tested it out in my LAB setup. One more thing, Now the SELECT * doesn't displays the data "Great", but still when i only choose the respective columns which i have granted select permissions it still brings out the whole data, so just want to check that is there a possibility to restrict the number of rows being shown/produces. Say out of 200 rows, the devs can only see 120 rows when issues the SELECT Columns command.

Comment: maybe you could grant them access to a view instead?